# How to split files according to a field and edit content

Tags: python, unix, split

I am not sure if I can do this using unix commands or I need a more complicated code, like python.

I have a big input file with 3 columns - id, different sequences (second column) grouped in different groups (3rd column).

```
Seq1        MVRWNARGQPVKEASQVFVSYIGVINCREVPISMEN       Group1
Seq2        PSLFIAGWLFVSTGLRPNEYFTESRQGIPLITDRFDSLEQLDEFSRSF  Group1
Seq3        HQAPAPAPTVISPPAPPTDTTLNLNGAPSNHLQGGNIWTTIGFAITVFLAVTGYSF  Group20
```

I would like:
split this file according the group id, and create separate files for each group; edit the info in each file, adding a ">" sign in the beginning of the id;  and then create a new row for the sequence

```
Group1.txt file
>Seq1
MVRWNARGQPVKEASQVFVSYIGVINCREVPISMEN       
>Seq2
PSLFIAGWLFVSTGLRPNEYFTESRQGIPLITDRFDSLEQLDEFSRSF

Group20.txt file
>Seq3
HQAPAPAPTVISPPAPPTDTTLNLNGAPSNHLQGGNIWTTIGFAITVFLAVTGYSF
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shell script should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename="data.txt"
while read line; do
    id=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $1}')
    sequence=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $2}')
    group=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $3}')
    printf ">${id}\n${sequence}\n" >> "${group}.txt"
done < "${filename}"
```

where `data.txt` is the name of the file containing the original data.

Importantly, the Group-files should not exist prior to running the script.

Answer (score 2):

AWK will do the trick:

```
awk '{ print ">"$1 "\n" $2 >> $3".txt"}' input.txt
```

Comment: this command it worked as well but the outputs were not .txt, I am not sure why, but it created different files

Comment: Yup, forgot to put ".txt" in double quotes. I'll fix it. It has no effect on the output except for adding the .txt extension.